# what is the proper syntax to add app token and query function to api json endpoint?

Tags: socrata, soda

I'm writing a program that queries an open data api by adding a query at the end of the api endpoint.  when I have tried adding the app_token tag I have either gotten a malformed url error or an unauthorized access error.  I have tried to access the endpoint with my app_token and I have successfully connected, but I can't seem to with the addition of my query.

what is the proper syntax in making concatenations like this? any guidance would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

For me this working fine:

`https://opendata.fcc.gov/resource/vakf-fz8e.json?$limit=1000&$offset=8000&$$app_token=myToken`

But if i place *$$app_token=myToken* parameter at the end of URL it won't work.

**Hope this will help!**